# What is they query format for date in Postgres?

Tags: javascript, postgresql, sequelize.js

I'm new to SQL. I made an SQL query, but I do not know a correct date format that I wish to use. I have syntax errors, that I can't show right now. Thanks very much for any assistance.

```
const getWhere = () => {
  const whereCondition = `"Report"."statusId" IN (${statusIds})
  ${params.startDate ? `AND "Report"."createdAt" >= DATE(${moment(params.startDate).format('YYYY-MM-DD')})` : ''}
  ${params.endDate ? `AND "Report"."createdAt" <= DATE(${moment(params.endDate).format('YYYY-MM-DD')})` : ''}`
  return whereCondition;
}
```

Comment: Tag your question properly that community can find it. It looks like Javascript to me, so I will add a temprorary tag.

Comment: Also you should add expected date format. From the code you've posted it is not clear of what you are trying to achive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ISO format (YYYY-MM-DD) is fine.

But the date literal must be a string, that is, surrounded by single quotes (`'`).